# Chat widget in customer portal

Tags: chatter

I want to show chat widget in customer portal. I have enabled it and it is working fine with salesforce user but not in customer portal. Any idea if that is possible as of now?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this functionality is not available for Portal users but there are some restricted options to interact with the customers. One of them is Chatter Answers which helps the internal team to interact with the customers and vice versa. Salesforce.com is also coming up with a new feature, that is, salesforce.com communities which is added in the Summer'13 release.

Comment: Chat currently isn't supported in communities either.