# Salesforce Chat Messenger in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, chatter, chat, widget

Can we use Chat messenger (the chat widget) in a Visualforce page? I have force.com Sites (as portals), and I want to include a chat messenger in it?  If this isn't possible, any other ideas on how to implement messenger features?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chat widget in customer portal](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12167/chat-widget-in-customer-portal)

Answer (score 1):

I believe so.

This page from Salesforce states that you can enable or disable within the visualforce
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring12/chatter+messenger

Quote from the page: "Developers can disable Chatter Messenger functionality within specific Visualforce pages by setting “showHeader” in the page component to false, or by changing ContentType to something other than text/plain."